# Verifying the existence of a derivative of an absolute value function at x = 0.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, absolute-value

I've been struggling with this question for a while, and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You could show differentiability at the origin from the definition; that's trivial. Or, here's a simple corollary of the Mean Value Theorem: If $f$ is continuous on $(-1,1)$, differentiable except at $0$, and $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)=L$ then $f$ is differentiable at the origin, with $f'(0)=L$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x>0$ we have $f(x)=x^4$, hence $f'(x)=4x^3$.

For $x<0$ we have $f(x)=-x^4$, hence $f'(x)=-4x^3$.

For $x=0$ we use the definition:

$$\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=|h^3|=|h|^3 \to 0$$

as $h \to 0.$ Hence $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0)=0.$

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your derivative calculation is correct but can be simplified in a different way for making the differentiability of $f$ much more obvious. By definition, $$\frac{d}{dx}(|x|)=\frac{x}{|x|}.$$
Now, if $f(x)=x|x^3|$, we can rewrite as $$f(x)=x|x^2 \cdot x|=x\cdot x^2\cdot |x|=x^3|x|.$$ Taking the derivative, we have
\begin{align*} f'(x)&=3x^2 |x| + x^3\cdot\frac{x}{|x|}\\
&=\frac{3x^2\cdot|x|^2 + x^4}{|x|}\\
&=\frac{4x^4}{|x|}\\
&=\frac{4x^2\cdot|x|^2}{|x|}\\
&=4x^2 |x|. \end{align*}
So, it is obvious now that the derivative exits at $x=0$. But as I said, one could derive at this result even from your calculation as follows:
\begin{align*}
\frac{4x^6}{|x^3|} &= \frac{4\cdot|x^3|^2}{|x^3|}\\
&= 4|x^3|\\
&= 4x^2|x|.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice on how to simplify.

Comment: Your initial calculations show that $f$  is differentiable at $x$ with $f'(x)=4x^2|x|$ **if** $x\ne0$. You say that makes it obvious that $f$ is differentiable at the origin - how does that follow?????????????????????????